# How to get the document field details in elastic Rule body?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, alert, elastic-stack

I have created elastic Rule which triggers alert when condition matches, and it's using webhook connector which hits the ServiceNow POST API to populate data in ServiceNow, but I need some specific field value from the hit document to pass it to the API.

I have tried below code.

Connector:

[image]

Rule Body:

```
{{#ParseHjson}}
{
    caller_id: "xyz"
    u_ticket_classification: "Request"
    category: "Software"
    subcategory: "Application"
    short_description: "{First hit document: {{context.hits.0.message}}"
}
{{/ParseHjson}}
```

But I am getting empty value for {{context.hits.0.message} please suggest a correct parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use like below:

`{{context.hits.0._source.message}`

Also, I am not sure why you are using `{{#ParseHjson}}` and may due to that also it might creating issue.

If you want to iterate all the result from hits then you can use below code:

```
{{#context.hits}}
Document with {{_id}} and hostname {{_source.host.name}} has
{{_source.system.memory.actual.free}} bytes of memory free
{{/context.hits}}
```

Comment: I have tried {{context.hits.0._source.message}} but it's not working and I am using {{#ParseHjson}} to send it as a Json body.

Comment: Hi @Sagar when I using `{{#context}}{{.}}{{/context}}` than I am getting `{"timestamp":"2024-01-29T08:30:22.648Z","viewInAppUrl":"https://elastic.xyz.com:5601/app/logs/link-to/default/logs?time=7022648","matchingDocuments":14,"conditions":"log.level equals error","group":null,"isRatio":false,"reason":"14 log entries in the last 5 mins. Alert when ≥ 1.","alertDetailsUrl":"https://elastic.xyz.com:5601/app/observability/alerts/cabc68c-acc3-4963-abdf-dfca"}`